# Need to read cart products from local storage angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

Need to fetch data from local storage in angular 4 . I have tried to implement this using following in file data.service.ts

```js
 JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('customerData')).then((val) => {
      if (val != null || val != undefined) this.customerData = val;
    });
```

But the following error was displayed in console

```html
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null
    at new DataService (data.service.ts:110)
    at _createClass (core.js:10889)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10861)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10846)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12083)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12573)
    at createClass (core.js:12443)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12280)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:13738)
    at createRootView (core.js:13627)
    at new DataService (data.service.ts:110)
    at _createClass (core.js:10889)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10861)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10846)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12083)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12573)
    at createClass (core.js:12443)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12280)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:13738)
    at createRootView (core.js:13627)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:775)
    at eval (zone.js:858)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4736)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:500)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1448
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly assign the value from **`localStorage`**,

```
 this.customerData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('customerData'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse()` doesn't return a promise but an object. So, you can skip the `then()` and directly assign it to a variable.

```
var val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('customerData'))
if (val != null || val != undefined) {
    this.customerData = val;
}
```